# Using composer, call class by uri REQUEST_URI dont'work whay?

Tags: php, composer-php

http://impare.local/postgres/Update

url 2 is the update, but don't call the class!

```
namespace postgres;    
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use postgres\Connection as Connection;<br>
use postgres\CreateTables as CreateTables;<br>
use postgres\UpdateTables as UpdateTables;<br>
use postgres\Stocs as Stocs;<br>
use postgres\persons\Persons as Persons;<br>
use postgres\core\Route as Route;<br>
use postgres\persons\Update as Update;<br>

$url = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : null;
$url = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));    

$class = $url[2];
$controller = new $class(); //Update Class
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: No errors, nothing

Comment: what is the value of `print_r($controller)`.

Comment: no values just blank; , if i call $controller = new Update;   it works. i dont understant i use this before but without caomposer

Comment: whats the value of $url[2]..?

Comment: As you mentioned **url 2 is the update** but Update is at index 4 not 2. So url 4 is Update. `$class = $url[4];` change this it will work

Comment: var_dump($url[2]);    is update

Comment: call  var_dump($url[4]);  is null in my broswer

Comment: @KlevisCipi what is the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and if value of `$url[2]` is update in lowercase then using `ucfist` method make the first letter Capital, as in your code **Update** class is available but not **update**.